# Identity Server and Invalid Signature

Tags: identityserver4

I know there are a lot of question about this but nothing I am finding is resolving my issue.

Setup:

- Server

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();

var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);

builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

- Config.Clients

```
// resource owner password grant client
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ro.client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
}
```

- TestUsers.Users

```
new TestUser
{
    SubjectId = "818727",
    Username = "alice",
    Password = "alice",
    Claims =
    {
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Alice Smith"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "Alice"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "AliceSmith@email.com"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.WebSite, "http://alice.com"),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Address, JsonSerializer.Serialize(address), IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json)
    }
}
```

Call via postman:
[image]

Response in postman:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkE1RkQ2QzlFN0I0QTYzRjJDOERBM0IyRDkxODA1MTAxIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MjE1NDk1OTYsImV4cCI6MTYyMTU1MzE5NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InJvLmNsaWVudCIsInN1YiI6IjgxODcyNyIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTYyMTU0OTU5NiwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJqdGkiOiJFNDYxMjg1NkRDMzhBNkYxRTE3OTRGRkE2OURGMjY2MiIsImlhdCI6MTYyMTU0OTU5Niwic2NvcGUiOlsiYXBpMSJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.mThB_nrdwF28hvSDGllfZuZLIAaHirUzf0XJpkkVAjtJeWh6t73uf05Zbtuxc0pvh81MSvAs38firgXew00XqBHKJtEE8aLQpitnzu5SUfAsAlLCz281T9V7yH-YblBTm5z9ZR-5rJBoqFwbPQ8j_GhZeCxskFKbpjIcdfXcndSBFywu2yM5NEow3YNdtxdFHqChDt1WNT9Mk0GV17iN0Rg6ZlMbgZcF0zEinJDfccvMWyWvbWvqvtl4E6Yq53kEKiD8Y5p3HU2Bac8J54sXVuhFKWammLkZwnF2Qw0h_cFkoocxmA6lyeXlLb2vWqmcdZg_fi_M2SHKuKm6GHT-6w",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "api1"
}
```

However when I paste the access_token into jwt.io the token is decoded fine with everything that I expect but is comes up as an invalid signature. This is affecting the validating the token in other places.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you use this in the server:

```
builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

IdentityServer will regenerate new signing keys on each deployment if the existing keyfile is not found. So in production you should not use AddDeveloperSigningCredential instead you should use the AddSigningCredential method to add a more permanent key.

see [this page](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/keys/)

Comment: Is the keyfile is valid for the deployment, then should not the signature and token be valid when the details are authenicated and returned?

Comment: yes, it should be valid, my answer is in the case if you redeploy, then already existing tokens might be invalid if the keys changes.